# Dart Flutter Uint8List

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does calling .reversed on an instance of Uint8List not return an instance of Uint8List in reversed byte order. Is there some logical reason for not returning a Uint8List in reversed byte order ?

```
Uint8List uint8List = Uint8List(20); //20 byte array

Uint8List reversed =  uint8List.reversed; //error not returning Uint8List
```

Comment: List<int> uint8List = Uint8List(20).reversed.toList(); //20 byte array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `reversed` property is inherited from the `Uint8List`'s superclass `List` (technically from `Iterable`, which is `List`'s superclass).

Since `reversed` is part of `Iterable`, it returns an `Iterable` and not an `Uint8List`. You can, of course, simply convert it to a List.

```dart
Uint8List reverseUint8List(Uint8List list) {
  return Uint8List.fromList(list.reversed.toList());
}
```

Long story short, it's to prevent having to duplicate 99% of the `reversed` code for each implementation of `Iterable`, and while it does not make sense for the output (a reversed list cannot suddenly become a queue/set/whatever), it does make sense implementation wise, since these data types are all similar in that regard.

Comment: would it not be more logical for the reversed property to be inherited from the Uint8List class and return a Uint8List in reversed byte order ?

Comment: The result there would make more sense, but that would mean that the same `reversed` implementation would have to exist for each `Iterable` class. If something were to change in the underlying implementation, it'd have to be changed in all of the different subclasses separately. It's unfortunately impossible for the `reversed` implementation (in `Iterable`) to know about the types of whichever classes will extend/implement it.

Comment: List<int> myList = [1,2,3] and call myList.reversed I receive an instance of List. Seems inconsistent that the same logic does not apply to Uint8List

Comment: The same logic does apply. If you try to assign `myList.reversed` to a `List<int>`, your compiler will throw an error, saying you cannot assign an `Iterable<int>` to a `List<int>`, same as with the `Uint8List`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this:

```dart
uint8List.reversed.toList()
```

as `reversed` returns an `Iterable`.

Comment: .toList() creates a List meaning we no longer have the benefits of working with Uint8List.

Comment: Correct, and?? The answer was regard to the question, that the OP wanted is a `List`. So to have a `List` you can use `.toList()`. You are out of context. That you are saying regard the code approach not what or why `reversed` not return a `List`.

Comment: I am the OP, I did not want a list. My question was in relation to the reversed property "is there some logical reason for not returning a Uint8List in reversed byte order"

Comment: Based on `//error not returning Uint8List` the context seems different. However My answer regard how to have a list after you've reversed a list. You can take this as purpose of answer. The code approach is something else that doesn't is based on your question or in my answer.